# Mavericks Captive Portal Request

Tags: macos, wifi

Anyone else *just* (15th July 2015) started seeing Apple's captive portal probe popup in 10.9.5? It may be a sneaky silent push (this isn't affecting 10.10.x) due to Flash security issues?

We've worked around this by pushing out (we use Munki) this to our devices and asking the user to reboot.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add ProbeParameters:SSIDExceptions:**SSIDName**:ProbeProtected bool true"
```

Answer (score 1):

try renaming /System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app, i used "no Captive Network Assistant.app" and restarted my Mac.

It's not a real solution just a workaround, it might be related to Apple Servers or something, but it works. Still waiting for Apple to solve this issue. Hope this helps!